# 2017 iMac Windows 10 on BootCamp 6.1 wont shutdown

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows

I have a brand new 2017 iMac on which installed windows 10 Pro. I installed the Bootcamp support software and for the most part the system works fine. Except for one annoying issue - I cant shutdown or hibernate the system it will only restart. I have done as much research i could and FWIW -

- Fast startup on windows 10 power settings is disabled.
- Installed and reinstalled Bootcamp windows 10 support software.
- Don't know if this is an issue the Intel Management engine.

At this point i am going to have to remove windows 10 and make do with windows 7 unless someone can help me with this problem. I am worries i have restarted so many time already it may damage the SSD or some other component of my shiny new iMac. Please help. Desperate!!!

Comment: Any clue guys? Please help.

Comment: Quick tests... make 2 .bat files, one `shutdown.exe /p /f` named 'shutdown.bat' & the other `shutdown.exe /g /f /t 00 ` named 'restart.bat'. Leave both on the desktop & see if both work when double-clicked, or just the restart one.

Comment: the same issue as yours, seem the driver is the root cause. may only the Bootcamp updated can resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

[iMac with bootcamp windows 10 reboots 3 seconds after shutdown (no fastboot, no wol)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343801/imac-with-bootcamp-windows-10-reboots-3-seconds-after-shutdown-no-fastboot-no)

I couldn't find a software fix but if you have any type of device or even a hub that supports USB PD connected to thunderbolt 3 port simply removing it while shutting down resolved my issue

by your description I couldn't tell if your issue is same as mine so do check what is connected to tb port